# Ionic ng-if generates error - ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-ng-if

I am trying to implement product categories in ionic application as received from the api. but while implementing the same i get the following error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."
```

Here is the code:

```
  <div class="width50" *ngFor="let object of dataList">
    <div *ng-if= "{{object?.categories[0]?.slug}} == single">
    <img src="{{object.images[0].src}}" width="150"  (click)="navigateToPage(object.id)" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

When i printed the value for `{{object?.categories[0]?.slug}}` the code worked fine and returned single.

using *ngif over *ng-if also does not seem to work it shows the following error.

```
`Template parse errors:
TypeError: key[0] is undefined ("
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="width50" *ngFor="let object of dataList">
    <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf= "{{object?.categories[0]?.slug}} == single">
    <img src="{{object.images[0].src}}" width="15"): ng:///AppModule/SinglePage.html@21:9
Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. "`
```

I believe that this might happen because maybe not all objects have values is the category array. So is there a way to ensure that the `*ng-if= "{{object?.categories[0]?.slug}} == single"` condition is checked only after ensuring that the category array is non-empty? also can we have both the conditions and loop on the same div ?

Comment: its *ngIf ..!!!

Comment: There is no `ng-if` directive in angular. You should use `*ngIf` instead

Comment: i referred here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766128/ionic-if-else-statement-to-display-and-show-data

Comment: Ionic 2/3 works on top of Angular (and not AngularJS) so when looking for how to do things in Ionic 2/3, make sure you're looking for posts tagged with `angular` and not `angularjs`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You made a type mistake it should be "*ngIf" not "ng-if",

replace this line,

```
<div *ng-if= "{{object?.categories[0]?.slug}} == single">
```

with

```
<div *ngIf= "object?.categories[0]?.slug == single">
```

problem is that you are trying to interpolate `object?.categories[0]?.slug` as a string inside your *ngIf condition. Remove the curly braces `{{}}` and your code will run fine

Comment: This does not seem to work, Updated the question on basis of the error received.

Comment: typo again! its not "ngif" its "ngIf". Uppercase "I" to be more specific

Comment: Also tried the upper case but issue remains the same.

Comment: I believe that this might happen because maybe not all objects have values is the category array. So is there a way to ensure that the slug condition is checked only after ensuring that the category array is non-empty?
Updated the question for further details.

Comment: that is not the case for "Template parse error". Can you post you html code here?

Comment: Already added the html code as that is the only code in the body for the page. and the exact error message is also added to the question do you require the html code too that is re-printed with the error.

Comment: Thsi works fine but due to loop each time an empty div is generated when the inner condition goes false so is there a way that we could merge the if condition with the div having the for loop?